# HTML and CSS markup for sprite naivgation images

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I'm trying to get an effect where I can have images next to my navigation links in the left menu all from a single sprite image. I'm not sure how I should be creating my markup in order to do this correctly. I want the whole image and text to be clickable in order to go to the URL.

**Possible solutions**

- Put an image tag to the left of the ahref link and link it to the same place.
- Use a background image on the ahref link with a margin to make space for it
- Use span tags

**Code**

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Z2qE5/

```
<ul id="sidenav">
    <li><a href="#" title="Home" class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_background_images#Sprites answer your question.

They use id in the `<li> tag` and then

```
#rss span{ background-position: -15px 0;}

#photos span{background-position: -30px 0;}

#links span{background-position: -45px 0;}
```

Comment: They use empty span tags, is that really the best approach?

Comment: Not sure if there is a right approach, but I don't see why this one could be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can check bootstrap way of doing this.. Here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/components/

There you can check their approach of doing this thing.
Briefly you can do folloing

```
    <ul id="sidenav">
    <li><a href="yourlink">Link text <span class="icon-class"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

In icon-class define position of your image from sprite.